# Why can't I assign to undeclared attributes of an object() instance but I can with custom classes?

Tags: python, class-structure

Basically I want to know why this works:

```
class MyClass:
  pass

myObj = MyClass()
myObj.foo = 'a'
```

But this returns an AttributeError:

```
myObj = object()
myObj.foo = 'a'
```

How can I tell which classes I can use undefined attributes with and which I can't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set attributes on any class with a `__dict__`, because that is where they are stored. `object` instances (which are weird) and any class that defines `__slots__` do not have one:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> hasattr(foo, "__dict__")
True
>>> foo.bar = "baz"
>>>
>>> class Spam(object):
...     __slots__ = tuple()
...
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> hasattr(spam, "__dict__")
False
>>> spam.ham = "eggs"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Spam' object has no attribute 'ham'
>>>
```

Comment: i.e., any user-defined class will do

Comment: @pberkes: nope, you can make classes without a `__dict__` (usually used for memory efficiency if you're expecting _lots_ of instances.